# Button is not getting disabled properly in the event target delegate in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I want to disable the button after the toaster message popup. The button is not getting disabled after the toaster message popup.

```
   <button (click)="setSubmitting($event.target, 'submitting')">submit</button>

and then in my component:

setSubmitting(element, text){
  element.textContent = text;
 <<Toaster Service Popup Code - "Submitting Now">
  element.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: You should disable your controls through the `FormsModule`. So `<button ... [disabled]="isDisabled">`

Comment: This will be a conflict at the global level.

Answer (score 0):

The button is not getting disabled after the toaster message popup. Maybe the code to disable the button isn't properly executing after the toaster message popup code. The `element.disabled = true;` is probably executing before the toaster message is shown to the user.

Add a `setTimeout` for 500ms before disabling the button so that the toaster message has time to appear on the screen.

Or use the `onShown` event to disable the button after the popup is shown like this:

```
setSubmitting(element, text){
  element.textContent = text;
 <<Toaster Service Popup Code - "Submitting Now">>
  .onShown.subscribe(() => {
    element.disabled = true;
  })
}
```

Comment: i tried setTimeout but it doesn't worked :(

Comment: try using the onShown event of the toaster service to disable the button. This way, the button will be disabled after the toaster message is displayed, and it should work as expected. Maybe your toaster service is not properly implemented, check the onShown event by adding a console.log inside the subscription.